# When creating pod it go into CrashLoopBackoff. Logs show "exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error."

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, exec

1. Using WordPress php-apache-7.4 as base image, I created a Docker file with few customisation and created an image. I am using the same docker-entrypoint.sh, wp-config-docker.php files from the Docker Hub official image.
2. Using the image when I create a container on Docker Desktop it works fine and I am able to load the WP page
3. I upload the same image to Docker Hub and from there and using that image created a pod on EKS cluster and I receive the error "exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error."

I am using the files from the below repo
https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/3b5c63b5673f298c14142c0c0e3e51edbdb17fd3/latest/php7.4/apache

Only Docker file in the above repo is modified to installed the memcached and copy wp-config.php. The other two files I am using without any changes.

I tried changing the docker-entrypoint.sh script to add `#!/bin/bash` as mentioned in some issue reported, also I tried to create a custom-entrypoint.sh to edit the original docker-entrypoint.sh script which was also suggested in another page but they didn't work.

custom-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -e 's/^exec "$@"/#exec "$@"/g' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
source docker-entrypoint.sh
exec "$@"
```

Trying to fix this, only thing is confusing is on Docker Desktop when I create using the same image it runs the cont without any error.

Comment: Did you try removing `\\` after exec "$@" ?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
sed -i -e 's/^exec "$@"/#exec "$@"/g' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
source docker-entrypoint.sh
exec "$@"`

Comment: Sorry to confuse, that was not part of the script, I added when i was posting the question. I edited the question to remove that.

Comment: You mention Docker Desktop; are you potentially building the image on an ARM-based M1 Mac, but then trying to run it on an x86-based cloud instance?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot for pointing this issue, yes it's due to mac M1 pro chip. Now it's fixed. I added the below platform to the docker file and then build the image. 

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 <image>-<version>

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in the comment above by David Maze, the issue is due to building the image on Mac M1 Pro.

To fix this I need to add `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 <image>-<version>` in the Dockerfile and build or you can run the below command while running the build

`docker build --platform=linux/amd64 <image>-<version>`

Both solutions will work. I added `FROM --platform=linux/amd64` to the Dockerfile and it's fixed now.

Comment: What if I rebuild an image on the host and issue the same?

Also, If I run docker run container succeed, but if I make same with Kubernetes it returns /bin/sh exec format error

Comment: It is very interesting, I was using my image to deploy google cloud run and was fine and working, then I started migrating it to DigitalOcean's k8s and was failing, pod didn't start with a similar issue, and I was following this answer, I mean `--platform=linux/amd64` and fixed, thanks